# IntelliJ wont show my files when loading or creating output

Tags: intellij-idea

I have the latest IntelliJ IDEA (2017.3) and for some reason, whenever a close a project and reopen it, files dissapear from project (they do show up in the explorer though), and I have to set up the SDK again. Same thing happens when I try to set the output directory to the project directory. I know I can show up the files using the `Import module (from .iml)` in the project structure dialog, but I am looking for a permanent solution, as it is quite annyoing setting up the SDK and importing the `src` module every time I open intellij.

Is there any permanent solution that anyone has found for this problem?

*TEST project example. This is **what it should show up** when opening the project.*
[image: What it should show up]

*TEST project example. This is **what actually  shows up** when opening the project.*
[image: What actually shows up]

*TEST project example. This is what it shows when selecting the project directory for the output.*
[image: Output]

Comment: Configure the module content and source roots: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-content-roots.html.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Cannot do that when there is no module imported.

Comment: Add a module first.

Comment: The whole point of my question was not to import modules. However, I tried what you are saying and still no success.

Comment: For some reason your project is not saved correctly. Check [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085) for errors. Make sure all the files in `.idea` directory can be saved. The issue can be caused by keeping the project in OneDrive managed folder or some similar file sharing solution.

Comment: OneDrive related issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/v2/issue/IDEABKL-7619. Move your files outside of OneDrive managed folder and it should fix the problem.

Comment: @CrazyCoder holy cow, you are right, post is an answer so that I can vote it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is [known to be caused by OneDrive](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/v2/issue/IDEABKL-7619). It's recommended to keep IDE projects outside of OneDrive managed folders.